# Formulario Android con Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy haciendo un formulario con un botón y al diseñar el botón lo pongo en el medio de la pantalla. En cambio cuando ejecuto la aplicación, este aparece en la parte izquierda de sobre el form.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Me pasa en todos los forms que hago.

Gracias.

Comment: pon el código de la pantalla

Comment: Hola Martin bienvenido, no te recomiendo que uses el editor de vistas, siempre es mejor que hagas el diseño editando el xml. sino siempre vas a depender de codigo autogenerado que por lo general es muy malo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de anclar los elementos en un sitio en concreto de la pantalla, clickeando en los circulos blancos y arrastrando las flechas hacia los extremos, saludos :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!